# Python - bytearray function with string literal

Tags: python

Learning about OpenCV in Python, I came across the function bytearray() which returns an array of bytes. Reading about this function on the internet, I saw an example whose outcome I cannot quite follow. The sample can be found here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-bytearray-function/

The code:

```
str = 'Geeksforgeeks'

array2 = bytearray(str, 'utf-16')

print(array2)
```

The outcome is:

```
bytearray(b'\xff\xfeG\x00e\x00e\x00k\x00s\x00f\x00o\x00r\x00g\x00e\x00e\x00k\x00s\x00')
```

While I do understand that \x is an escape sequence indicating a hex value, the values following to the ff, fe, 00 etc do not make sense to me when talking about characters.

For instance, the string starts with quotation marks followed by a capital g, i.e. G.

The outcome of the bytearray function is `\xfeG`

I am having difficulties to map \xfeG to the capital letter G.
If we assume \x to indicate the following to be a hex number, I would read it as 0xfe = 254. Looking at the ASCII table for this number, I get something completely different than G. and 0xfeG does not exist.

Could someone help me with that because I am a little bit lost.

Thank you,

Comment: You want to read up on UTF-16 encoding, e.g. at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16 .

Comment: FEFF is the byte order mark (BOM) of the UTF-16 encoded byte array. Depending on the endianness, these two bytes may be flipped.

Comment: ` 'G'.encode('utf16')` ->  `b'\xff\xfeG\x00'` - the first two bytes are the byte order mark (BOM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the values following to the ff, fe, 00 etc do not make sense to me when talking about characters.

That's because you don't know how [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) works.

The 16 in UTF-16 refers to how many bits characters use, i.e. each character will use 2 bytes.

When you have two bytes `A` and `B`, you can physically place them as `AB` (that's called "little-endian") or `BA` (that's "big endian"). That's called *byte order*, and it's important to know for successful conversion of bytes back to characters ("decoding") later.

For this, the byte string starts with a byte-order mark ("BOM"). `\xff\xfe` is the BOM for the "little endian" type.

Characters like `G` do not need the full 16 bit, so the second byte stays empty (`\x00`) and `G` becomes `\x47\x00`. Python displays characters for all bytes that are less than 127, so this gets displayed as `G\x00`, but it's the same thing.

Little-endian encoding:

```
b'\xff\xfeG\x00e\x00e\x00k\x00s\x00f\x00o\x00r\x00g\x00e\x00e\x00k\x00s\x00'
 'LE BOM |G   |e   |e   |k   |s   |f   |o   |r   |g   |e   |e   |k   |s    '
```

Big-endian encoding (note the different BOM):

```
b'\xfe\xff\x00G\x00e\x00e\x00k\x00s\x00f\x00o\x00r\x00g\x00e\x00e\x00k\x00s'
 'BE BOM  |   G|   e|   e|   k|   s|   f|   o|   r|   g|   e|   e|   k|   s'
```

Both byte strings decode properly with `.decode('UTF-16')`, because the BOM informs `.decode()` about the string's internal layout.

Other characters occupy more of the 16 bits. For example `字` becomes `\x57\x5b` in little-endian UTF-16, which Python somewhat unhelpfully displays as `W[`.

```
b'\x57\x5b'.decode('UTF-16')   # -> '字'
b'W['.decode('UTF-16')         # -> '字'
```

When a BOM is missing, Python will assume "little-endian" by default. Otherwise you need to be explicit about the type:

```
b'[W'.decode('UTF-16-BE')      # -> '字'
```